# An XHTML test page

Tags: html, css, testing, xhtml

Does any have a link or something to a dummy XHTML test page to use for CSS design?

Like a page which contains sample content with all of the HTML tags

Comment: You could try the [CSS Zengarden](http://csszengarden.com/)?

Comment: By "test page" do you mean practice exercises for learning how to use CSS to control various HTML elements?

Comment: no, just page with elements like lists, tables etc. (if possible all of the tags possible in xthml). Then I can use it this to create CSS rules for each element easier.

Comment: I found one here: http://wp-themes.com/?p=36

Comment: found another one here: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/test/xhtml-suite/xhtml11.xhtml

Comment: @alex: ah I get what you mean now. Anyway other people beat me to good answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [CSS zen garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/).

Edit: I've just found [HTML Element Test Code - Valid Strict XHTML](http://snipplr.com/view/22504/html-element-test-code--valid-strict-xhtml/) that has all possible HTML Elements in it (that looks exactly the same as @Alex posted in the comment).

Answer (score 2):

Great for testing.

http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

HTML tests:

- http://www.play-hookey.com/htmltest/
- http://www.w3.org/People/mimasa/test/

I prefer documentation..

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/zengarden-sample.html) has sample pages that you can use.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, at least say why. This answer isn't incorrect. But thanks for making my rep a multiple of 10.